# Why constructor returns a null in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
      $notification = Notification::where('read_status', 0)->get();
    }
}
```

In `$notification` variable constructor returns an `null` while data is present in notifications table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors do not return values, their only purpose is to instantiate class instances.

If you want to fetch data and use it in your class, you can do something like:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    private $notifications;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->notifications = Notification::where('read_status', 0)->get();
    }
}
```

or

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    private $notifications;

    public function __construct()
    {
         $this->loadUnreadNotifications();
    }

    private function loadUnreadNotifications()
    {
        $this->notifications = Notification::where('read_status', 0)->get();
    }
}
```

After which you can use `$this->notifications` in your other controller methods.